# Why does Azure Function retry mechanism making more attempts than max configured and keep trying past the successful one?

Tags: azure, azure-functions

I wonder why Azure Function retry mechanism taking more attempts than configured (`"maxRetryCount": 2`) and keep trying past the successful one, I have 2 attempts setup in host.json configuration, but I see more are taken for any failed document I checked, usually from 6 to 9. What even is less explainable I clearly see more attempts are done past the successful retry like one picture below (12:20:54), and I'm confident no exception raises in code in case of "Successfully uploaded document"

[image]

when I compare different log entries they are different on operation_Id, operation_ParentId and itemId, but same for the rest like appId

host.json

```
{
  ...
  "retry": {
    "strategy": "fixedDelay",
    "maxRetryCount": 2,
    "delayInterval": "00:00:30"
  }
}
```

Comment: I have the same behaviour, I also tried setting max deque, all with no luck, the function just keeps retrying 10 times.

Answer (score 1):

I do not see this behavior anymore after couple of days since I introduced the retry mechanism settings. Looks like Azure 'adjusted' itself to work as expected, I did not change anything - code or configuration, not sure what it was, some kind of a glitch I guess.

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure if you have any other underlaying retry mechanism or not that could affect the Az Func retry policy. Here is a good explanation regarding [Azure Functions error handling and retries](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/functions-bindings-error-pages?tabs=csharp).

What I was thinking at the beginning of my answer was because of [this](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/functions-bindings-error-pages?tabs=csharp#using-retry-support-on-top-of-trigger-resilience):

> The function app retry policy is independent of any retries or resiliency that the trigger provides. The function retry policy will only layer on top of a trigger resilient retry. For example, if using Azure Service Bus, by default queues have a message delivery count of 10. The default delivery count means after 10 attempted deliveries of a queue message, Service Bus will dead-letter the message. You can define a retry policy for a function that has a Service Bus trigger, but the retries will layer on top of the Service Bus delivery attempts.

Comment: yes, I read the article, but still can't match what the article say to my app behavior. The only type of trigger I have is time trigger. The Azure Function orchestrator (durable function) is triggered by daily scheduler (TimerTrigger), which runs Az Function with CallActivityWithRetryAsync() where "Error processing document .." exception occurs that you can see on the screenshot above. Maybe the durable function calling another function flow makes the retry mechanism work different way